# Input buffer structure in an AudioUnit

Tags: c++, xcode, audio, buffer, audiounit

I've written a simple audiounit that should swap the left and right channels of a stereo source. A ported version of this code worked fine in C for a command-line program that used the BASS library, but I'm having trouble getting the same code to work in Xcode for an audiounit.

For a buffer input of, for example, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, i would expect the stereo reversal to be {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5}.

My code correctly reverses the samples in this manner, but all I hear is some sort of low-pass filtering, rather than a stereo reversal of samples.

The first 4 values in my input buffer are: 
0.000104
0.000101
0.000080
0.000113

The output is:
0.000101
0.000104
0.000113
0.000080

Have I misunderstood something about the way the input/output buffers are structured?

```
void        First::FirstKernel::Process(    const Float32   *inSourceP,
                                                Float32         *inDestP,
                                                UInt32          inSamplesToProcess,
                                                UInt32          inNumChannels, 
                                                bool            &ioSilence )
{


if (!ioSilence) {                                                 

    const Float32 *sourceP = inSourceP;  
    Float32  *destP = inDestP;  
    for (int i = inSamplesToProcess/2; i>0; --i) { 


        *(destP+1) = *sourceP;
        *destP = *(sourceP+1);

        sourceP = sourceP +2;
        destP = destP +2;
}   
}   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that this code isn't working is because you are using AudioUnit kernels, which call your plugin to process a single channel of audio data (if I understand correctly). While kernels can be quite convenient in some cases, it's definitely not going to work for a plugin which does interdependent stereo processing. You are being passed the number of channels in your callback -- have you checked this value?

Regardless, you should instead inherit from the `AUEffectBase` class and override the `ProcessBufferLists()` method. Then you will get a proper [AudioBufferList](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) structure which contains non-interlaced buffers for each audio channel. It will also give you much finer control over the rendering process than using kernels.

*Edit*: Ok, it turns out that the Kernel callback is always being passed 1 channel of audio. Also, overridding `Render()` as I originally suggested is not the best way to do this. According to a comment in the `AUEffectBase.h` source code:

> If your unit processes N to N channels, and there are no interactions between channels,
>   it can override NewKernel to create a mono processing object per channel.  Otherwise,
>   don't override NewKernel, and instead, override ProcessBufferLists.

As `AUEffectBase` isn't part of the "standard" AudioUnit code, you will need to add the cpp/h files into your project. They can be found under the AudioUnit SDK root in the `AudioUnits/AUPublic/OtherBases` folder. So for your plugin, that would look something like this:

MyEffect.h:

```
#include "AUEffectBase.h"

class MyEffect : public AUEffectBase {
public:
  // Constructor, other overridden methods, etc.
  virtual OSStatus ProcessBufferLists(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags &ioActionFlags,
                                      const AudioBufferList &inBuffer,
                                      AudioBufferList &outBuffer,
                                      UInt32 inFramesToProcess);


private:
  // Private member variables, methods
};
```

MyEffect.cpp:

```
// Other stuff ....

OSStatus MyEffect::ProcessBufferLists(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags &ioActionFlags,
                                      const AudioBufferList &inBuffer,
                                      AudioBufferList &outBuffer,
                                      UInt32 inFramesToProcess) {
  const float *srcBufferL = (Float32 *)inBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData;
  const float *srcBufferR = (Float32 *)inBuffer.mBuffers[1].mData;
  float *destBufferL = (Float32 *)outBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData;
  float *destBufferR = (Float32 *)outBuffer.mBuffers[1].mData;

  for(UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inFramesToProcess; ++frame) {
    *destBufferL++ = *srcBufferL++;
    *destBufferR++ = *srcBufferR++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After much effort I managed to uncover a series of forum posts with people experiencing the same problem, primarily because the AU example given by apple isn't a stereo processor. Thanks for the help!
I'm still having trouble overriding Render() though; it's been a while since I delved into this sort of thing and I'm a bit rusty.
First, in the header file I define a virtual function called Render that takes the same arguements as the one in AUEffectBase. Then, in my cpp file, I build the render function 'First::Render', which calls the Process function... is that the correct procedure?

Comment: Btw, inNumChannels is always 1 in the current version of AudioUnits; I think it's there to give headroom for development in future versions.

Comment: @JimmyB Yeah, it turns out that kernels are strictly for N-N processing as I had suspected. I added some more info and example code to my answer to reflect that. Hope this helps you, and don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solves the problem!

Comment: Without overriding these methods in this manner, there would be a separate kernel instantiated for each channel, is that correct? In a separate project, I'm trying to implement a biquad filter (no interactions between channels) and it's just giving me a weird ring modulator effect. The previous filter I wrote in C using the BASS library worked just fine, but that only had one channel of interleaved samples.
I think I need to better understand how AUs process the data before I proceed any further... If you have any information along those lines I'd be really grateful!
Thanks so much again!

Comment: @JimmyB Kernels are a convenient N-N processing framework built on top of AudioUnits, but you don't have to use them. If you have additional problems, you should make a new question though. :)

Comment: I'm getting errors for the two processing lines in your code: 'no match for 'operator[]' in 'outBuffer->AudioBufferList::mBuffers[0][frame]'
any ideas? I'm not too familiar with this stuff, so if this is an easy fix, or you could point me in the right direction, i'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi! Just thought i'd let you know that I'd cracked this now :)

http://pastebin.com/mtrRRH6k

Comment: @JimmyB, cool, I updated my answer with the code you put in pastebin. Nice fix!